# Using Spring Roo to handle MVC and Vaadin without using JPA

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

Im evaluating spring roo for a new project we are starting.  the problem i seem to have run into is im not using Hibernate or any other ORM package for database.  we are using Mybatis.  that means we do not want JPA installed in our project.

every time i type hint, roo tells me that i must install JPA (don't want to do that as Mybatis does not use JPA).  but where it really effects me is when i do something like this

```
web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.controller.FirstController
```

it returns this

```
Command 'web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.controller.FirstController' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
```

does this mean that roo will not allow these other functions without JPA?  is there a way that i can trick roo into using these functions without installing JPA?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to JPA to use spring roo.  However, you can take it out later.
You can create have it create repository classes for you.  Then you can easily convert these to mybatis style, by adding the mybatis annotations.